# Como posso usar a nova API de datas do Java 8?

Tags: android, android-studio, java-8

Gostaria de saber como compilo no meu Gradle Build para ficar disponível a nova API de datas do java 8 no meu android studio

Comment: Vê se ajuda: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21212790/2570426

Comment: Amigo, a pergunta como formulada atualmente está extremamente vaga, por gentileza [leia como fazer uma pergunta adequada](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) e forneça mais detalhes a cerca do seu projeto, o que você já fez e qual seu nível de conhecimento a respeito. Sem isso, o máximo que vão poder te fornecer é um *negativo* e talvez, alguns links.

Comment: Cara, a pergunta é bem simples e direta. Atualmente eu uso o estilo de datas Date e Calendar no android studio, e quero apenas o 'compile' para ficar disponivel a nova API de datas do Java 8. Simples

Comment: Ack Lay, o que eu quero é exatamente saber como configuro meu gradle para ser compativel

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Acho que nenhuma das respostas atende ao OP, dado que ele tem interesse na JSR 310, que é a nova API para trabalhar com datas sem ter que <del>se estressar</del> lidar com as classes `Date` e `Calendar` do Java.

Acredito que usar a compatibilidade do Java 8 dada pelo [finado Jack](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/03/future-of-java-8-language-feature.html) não fornece a JSR 310.

Minha sugestão é ir para suas versões portadas, ou seja, usar o `Joda Time` ou o `ThreeTen ABP`, sendo que eu tenho recomendado mais a segunda opção.

Segue a documentação da [`Three Ten ABP`](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) e a documentação da [`Joda Time`](https://github.com/dlew/joda-time-android#why-this-library)

Você poderá usar facilmente adicionando a dependëncia do Gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'net.danlew:android.joda:2.9.7'
}
```

ou

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.jakewharton.threetenabp:threetenabp:1.0.5'
}
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado! Era realmente isso :D

Answer (score 8):

**Edição 2020/06/01**

Com o Android Studio 4.0 e Android Gradle plugin 4.0.0 o suporte para Java 8 foi estendido, permitindo usar mais Api's sem requer um nível de API mínimo.

Para [habilitar o suporte](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support?utm_source=android-studio-4-0&utm_medium=studio-assistant-stable#library-desugaring) a essas APIs é necessário incluir, no build.gradle, o seguinte:

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
    // Required when setting minSdkVersion to 20 or lower
    multiDexEnabled true
  }

  compileOptions {
    // Flag to enable support for the new language APIs
    coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true
    // Sets Java compatibility to Java 8
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  }
}

dependencies {
  coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.0.5'
}
```

[Lista de Api's suportadas](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table).

---

**Edição 2019/04/27**

A [java.time](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/package-summary) está disponível a partir da APi 26.
Requere `compileSdkVersion >= 26` e `minSdkVersion >= 26`

---

**Edição 2017/11/10**

Se estiver a usar o Android Studio 3.0 configure o seu *build.gradle* da seguinte forma:

```
android {
  ...
  // Configure only for each module that uses Java 8
  // language features (either in its source code or
  // through dependencies).
  compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  }
}
```

Para mais informações veja [Use Java 8 Language Features](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support.html).

---

O Android não suporta todas as características do Java 8 e a maior parte das que suporta só podem ser usadas no desenvolvimento de aplicação para Android 7(API 24).

**Características suportadas:**(em qualquer API *level*)

- Default and static interface methods
- Lambda expressions
- Repeatable annotations
- Method References
- Type Annotations

**Reflexão e APIs relacionadas à linguagem:**(API *level* 24 ou superior)

- java.lang.FunctionalInterface
- java.lang.annotation.Repeatable
- java.lang.reflect.Method.isDefault()

**APIs utilitárias:**(API *level* 24 ou superior)

- java.util.function
- java.util.stream

Como pode verificar a API de datas do Java 8 não está incluída nas APIs suportadas e portanto não a pode usar.

Se no entanto quiser utilizar os outros recursos do Java 8 configure o seu *build.gradle* da seguinte forma:

```
android {
  ...
  defaultConfig {
    ...
    jackOptions {
      enabled true
    }
  }
  compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Para ativar os recursos de linguagem do [Java 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/pt/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) e o Jack para seu projeto, insira o seguinte código abaixo no arquivo `build.gradle` de nível do módulo. O `sourceCompatibility` e `targetCompatibility`. Veja como deve ficar:

```
android {
  ...
  defaultConfig {
    ...
    jackOptions {
      enabled true
    }
  }
  compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  }
}
```

Veja mais detalhes para [**uso de recursos de linguagem do Java 8**](https://developer.android.com/guide/platform/j8-jack.html?hl=pt-br) na documentação.

<sup>**Nota:** Só é possível usar os recursos do Java 8 no Android Studio 2.1 ou superior.</sup>