# Como setar o valor de um spinner de forma elegante

Tags: java, android

Prezados em uma atividade onde estamos fazendo uma alteração, estou setando o valor do(s) spinner(rs) de forma bruta

```
     for(int i = 0; i < clienteAdapter.getCount(); i++) {

            Cliente elemento = (Cliente) clienteAdapter.getItem(i);

            if(elemento.getId() == pedido.getId_cliente()) {
                spCliente.setSelection(i);
                break;
            }
        }
```

Estou obtendo os dados que populam o Spinner do SQLite, teria uma forma mais elegante de fazer isto?

Answer (score 0):

Se você estiver utilizando java8 pra compilar, pode usar filter para pesquisar na lista com predicados:

```
        Optional elemento = lista.stream().filter(c -> c.getId() == 1).findFirst();
        if (elemento.isPresent()){
            [...]
        }
```

Comment: O problema é que o Android(por enquanto) [não suporta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/190262/2541) *java 8 streams*

Comment: Retrolambda e outras bibliotecas de compatibilidade podemte ajudar a escrever Java 8 e rodar onde desejar. Não me lembro qual era o processador para compatibilidade de streams, mas creio que na documentação do retrolambda ele cita alguém

Comment: Parece-me que esse rapaz fez o trabalho de backport : https://github.com/streamsupport/streamsupport/

Comment: Ramaral e Jefferson, verdade, não havia percebido. Estava usando o Android Studio 3.0 Dev. Preview e testando com um android 7.1.2.

Comment: Por isso eu disse "por enquanto". Com o Android Studio 3 é possível no entanto apenas para apps com minSdk 24 ou superior.