# Usando java.lang.reflect.Parameter em aplicações android

Tags: java, android, reflexão

Olá.
Estou tentando implementar uma aplicação android (com a IDE Android Studio) que usa Reflections para acessar determinados atributos de uma classe.
Porém, ao utilizar a classe `java.lang.reflect.Parameter` em versões inferiores a 26 (Android 8.0) o aplicativo fecha e dá erro (NoSuchMethodException)
Minha dúvida é, eu não consigo utilizar as propriedades dessa classe em versões anteriores a 26??? E por acaso existe um "substituto"?

Comment: Você pode postar o código?

Comment: Esse método só existe no JAVA 8. [Apenas parte](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/190262/2541) do JAVA 8 é suportado em versões antigas do Android.

Answer (score 1):

O que estava causando erro era um método da classe `java.lang.reflect.Method` (`getParameters()`, que retorna um array de parâmetros correspondentes ao método).

```
Parameter[] parameters = meumetodo.getParameters();
```

Alterei meu código para que retornasse apenas a lista de tipos de parâmentros (através do método, getParameterTypes()), assim me retornando a um array de classes correspondentes aos tipos de parametros.

```
Class<?>[] parameterTypes = meumetodo.getParameterTypes();
```

Não encontrei muita informação na internet sobre esse erro, apenas o que o próprio Android Studio me informou (a API mínima para usar a classe Parameter deve ser 26 ou posterior).
Abaixo a mensagem do erro quando eu uso Parameter:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]