# Somar meses a um Calendar sem modificar a instância original

Tags: java, android, data, calendar

Estou implementando um sistema no qual eu seto uma data específica em uma variável do tipo `Calendar` e depois preciso manipulá-la.

Gostaria de pegar o valor de alguns meses adicionado:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH,4);
```

O que eu gostaria é pegar essa data adicionada em outra variável, que não afete o `Calendar` já que é uma classe Singleton.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O fato de [`getInstance()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#getInstance()) ser estático não significa que `Calendar` é um *Singleton*.

Um *Singleton* significa que existirá [somente uma instância](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/singleton/info) da classe na JVM. Mas `getInstance()` sempre retorna uma nova instância:

```
Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar c2 = Calendar.getInstance();
System.out.println(c1 == c2); // false
```

O código acima imprime `false`, já que `c1` e `c2` não são a mesma instância. Veja que, apesar de `getInstance()` ser estático, uma nova instância sempre é retornada.

Neste caso, o método `getInstance()` está funcionando com um [*static factory method*](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/225042). Só porque existe um método estático que retorna uma instância, não quer dizer necessariamente que esta instância será um *singleton*.

---

### Como copiar uma instância

O detalhe é que `getInstance()` retorna um `Calendar` que corresponde à data e hora atual. Ou seja, `c1` e `c2` não terão exatamente os mesmos valores.

Se você quer obter uma nova instância com os mesmos valores da original, basta copiá-la, usando o método [`clone()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#clone()). Em seguida você pode alterar o clone à vontade, sem modificar o original:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

// criar outro Calendar, com o mesmo valor do original
Calendar clone = (Calendar) calendar.clone();
clone.add(Calendar.MONTH, 4); // somar 4 meses
```

Com isso, o clone pode ser alterado conforme necessário, e o `calendar` original não terá o seu valor alterado.

---

### `GregorianCalendar`

<sup><sub>*Havia uma resposta em que o autor da pergunta dizia que havia encontrado uma solução, usando diretamente `GregorianCalendar`. A resposta foi apagada, mas de qualquer forma deixei esta explicação adicional como complemento.*</sub></sup>

[`GregorianCalendar`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/GregorianCalendar) é uma subclasse de `Calendar`, e não há problema em usá-la diretamente, se assim for o desejado. O detalhe é que você provavelmente já estava usando esta classe sem saber.

Isso acontece porque `Calendar` é uma classe abstrata, o que significa que não é possível criar instâncias diretamente com `new Calendar()`. Então `getInstance()` na verdade retorna alguma subclasse de `Calendar`, baseado no [`Locale`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale) padrão da JVM. E na grande maioria dos casos* (para quase todos os locales), o retorno é um `GregorianCalendar`:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
System.out.println(calendar.getClass()); // class java.util.GregorianCalendar
```

Claro que você pode usar `GregorianCalendar` diretamente se quiser. Mas também pode continuar usando `getInstance()` sem problemas, e se quiser que um `Calendar` não seja modificado, crie cópias do mesmo usando `clone()`.

***** *Pelo que vi na [documentação do Android](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar), `GregorianCalendar` parece ser a única subclasse nativa. Porém, no JDK existem outras implementações, por isso alguns locales [podem retornar subclasses diferentes](https://ideone.com/5oAq3Y).*

---

### `java.time`

Dependendo da versão do Anroid, você também pode usar o [pacote `java.time`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/package-summary) ([veja aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/190262/112052) os requisitos para poder usá-la). Esta nova API de datas é muito superior à `Date` e `Calendar`, e na minha opinião, vale muito a pena migrar seu código para usá-la.

Um detalhe interessante e que ajudaria no seu caso é que todas as classes são imutáveis, então quaisquer operações (como somar meses a uma data) sempre retornam uma nova instância. Um exemplo com [`java.time.LocalDate`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/LocalDate):

```
LocalDate hoje = LocalDate.now(); // data atual
// somar 4 meses (retorna uma nova instância)
LocalDate maisQuatroMeses = hoje.plusMonths(4);
```

[`plusMonths()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/LocalDate#plusMonths(long)) (e todos os outros métodos para somar/subtrair dias/meses/anos) retorna uma nova instância, então a variável `hoje` permanecerá a mesma (não há a necessidade de clonar a instância, como fizemos com `Calendar`).

Outro detalhe é que nesta API há várias classes diferentes para representar datas e horas, diferente da API anterior, que só possui `Date` e `Calendar`.

Por exemplo, `LocalDate` representa somente a data (dia, mês e ano). Há também [`LocalTime`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/LocalTime), para representar horas (somente hora, minuto, segundo e frações de segundo), [`LocalDateTime`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/LocalDateTime) para data e hora, [`ZonedDateTime`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/ZonedDateTime) para lidar com fusos horários, etc. Sugiro que veja o [tutorial da Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) e [esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177129/112052) para mais detalhes sobre esta API.