# Como subtrair 2 string de horas

Tags: java, android-studio, data

Estou a fazer um projeto em Java no Android Studio em que tenho uma base de dados conectada a uma BD num servidor.

Em uma das tabelas, possuo 2 horas, `hora_inicio` e `hora_fim` que são extraídas para string.

Pretendo fazer a subtração entre elas, ou seja, `hora_fim - hora_inicio`, mas como são do tipo string e as horas possuem o `:` exemplo, `"14:20"`, não consigo fazer essa subtração.

Tentei converter para `int`, mas o código dá erro. Como posso fazer para fazer a subtração?

Meu código:

```
 private void Escrever_Estatisticas(View mainlayout) {
        FormSolicitarViagem.obterDataHoraServidor();
        
       //vai buscar a data atual -> data
        Date data = new Date(FuncoesUTEIS.reduzirXDias(FormSolicitarViagem.getMinData().getTime(),1)); //data minima é data posterior ao dia atual
        String data_minima_estatisticas = data.toString().substring(0,7)+ "-01"; //extrai somente os primeiros caracteres da string -> temos ano e mes e adicionamos o dia

        LocalDataBase bd = new LocalDataBase(getContext());
        String sqlAndroid = "select * from viagens_condutor where estado = 2 and data_viagem >= '" + data_minima_estatisticas + "'"; //base de dados local do android -> só tem a pessoa em causa
        Cursor cursor = bd.executar_select(bd.dbr, sqlAndroid);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        String Total_km = null;
        int totalKm = 0;
        int totalhoras = 0;
        String Total_horas_viagem = null;
        int nviagens=0;
        String num_viagens = null;
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) { //se não estiver na última posição
            String km = cursor.getString(3);
            // totalhoras_viagens = cursor.getString(6);
            int converterkm = Integer.parseInt(km);
            totalKm += converterkm;

            String hora_inicio = cursor.getString(10);
            Log.e("in", hora_inicio);
            String hora_fim = cursor.getString(11);
            Log.e("out", hora_fim);
            //int converter_hora_inicio = Integer.parseInt(hora_inicio);
            //int converter_hora_fim = Integer.parseInt(hora_fim);

            nviagens+=1;

            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

Uma alternativa é usar a [API `java.time`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/package-summary) - [veja aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/190262/112052) a configuração e requisitos necessários para usá-la no Android (e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177129/112052) tem mais detalhes sobre a API) - se não puder usá-la, deixei outras alternativas mais abaixo.

---

Se você tem duas strings no formato "HH:mm", uma alternativa é usar um [`LocalTime`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/LocalTime), que representa justamente um horário. O formato "hora:minuto" (cada um com 2 dígitos) está de acordo com a norma [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), e pode ser feito o *parsing* diretamente. Ex:

```
LocalTime horario = LocalTime.parse("14:20");
```

Com isso você consegue fazer o *parsing* das strings. Já para subtrair uma da outra, o que você quer exatamente como resultado? A quantidade total de horas e minutos entre elas? Somente o total em minutos (ou segundos, ou qualquer outra unidade)?

Enfim, como as strings só possuem hora e minuto (assume-se que os segundos sempre são zero), uma alternativa seria calcular o total de minutos entre elas, usando um [`ChronoUnit`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit):

```
LocalTime inicio = LocalTime.parse("10:00");
LocalTime fim = LocalTime.parse("14:20");
// diferença em minutos
int diffMinutes = (int) ChronoUnit.MINUTES.between(inicio, fim);
int horas = diffMinutes / 60;
int minutos = diffMinutes % 60;
System.out.printf("A diferença entre %s e %s é de %d horas e %d minutos\n",
                  inicio.toString(), fim.toString(), horas, minutos);
// A diferença entre 10:00 e 14:20 é de 4 horas e 20 minutos
```

O [método `between`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit#between(java.time.temporal.Temporal,%20java.time.temporal.Temporal)) retorna um `long`, mas como estou calculando a diferença em minutos, e um `LocalTime` só possui a informação do horário (ou seja, **estamos assumindo que ambos os horários referem-se ao mesmo dia)**, o valor não ultrapassará 1440, então podemos fazer o *cast* para `int` sem problemas.

Se quiser formatar a diferença como `04:20`, pode fazer assim:

```
System.out.printf("%02d:%02d\n", horas, minutos); // 04:20
```

---

Se não puder usar o `java.time`, uma alternativa é fazer o cálculo manualmente:

```
// método auxiliar para "normalizar" o horário
public int totalMinutes(String hora) {
    String[] partes = hora.split(":");

    return Integer.parseInt(partes[0]) * 60 + Integer.parseInt(partes[1]);
}

int diffMinutes = totalMinutes("14:20") - totalMinutes("10:00");
// restante do código igual
```

Claro que o método acima pode ser melhorado, pois ele não verifica se a string realmente está no formato "HH:mm", se os valores estão corretos (por exemplo, "99:99" deveria dar erro), etc.

---

Você também pode usar um [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat), mas precisa se atentar para alguns detalhes. Esta classe só trabalha com [`Date`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date), que por sua vez, representa um [*timestamp*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/70473/112052), então ela não consegue trabalhar "apenas com horário" (se não é fornecida uma data na string, internamente ela seta valores *default*). Por exemplo:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
System.out.println(sdf.parse("10:00")); // Thu Jan 01 10:00:00 BRT 1970
```

Repare que apesar do *parsing* ser feito somente com horário, a data foi setada para 1 de janeiro de 1970. Você pode ver mais detalhes sobre o comportamento de `Date` e `SimpleDateFormat` [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/370367/112052) (principalmente na seção "Datas e timezones").

Além disso, `SimpleDateFormat` aceita valores inválidos, como "99:99", fazendo ajustes bem estranhos:

```
System.out.println(sdf.parse("99:99")); // Mon Jan 05 04:39:00 BRT 1970
```

Para evitar esses problemas (além de outros, como considerar o timezone *default* da JVM, e efeitos como horário de verão podem causar problemas no cálculo da diferença), uma alternativa é setá-lo para não-leniente (para não considerar valores como "99:99") e mudar o timezone para UTC (que não sofre efeitos de horário de verão):

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
sdf.setLenient(false); // setar para não-leniente, assim não aceita valores como 99:99
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")); // UTC não sofre efeitos do horário de verão

Date inicio = sdf.parse("10:00");
Date fim = sdf.parse("14:20");

int diffMinutes = (int) ((fim.getTime() - inicio.getTime()) / (1000 * 60));
int horas = diffMinutes / 60;
int minutos = diffMinutes % 60;
System.out.printf("A diferença entre %s e %s é de %d horas e %d minutos\n",
                  sdf.format(inicio), sdf.format(fim), horas, minutos);
```

Usei o [método `getTime()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date#getTime()), que retorna o valor do *timestamp* em milissegundos, então subtraindo um do outro, obtenho a diferença em milissegundos, bastando ajustar os cálculos para obter a diferença em minutos.

Infelizmente, com `Date` e `SimpleDateFormat`, não há outros meios de se calcular diferença entre datas.

Answer (score 0):

Você tem que converter seu horário em um formato onde possa calcular.
Uma maneira é essa:

```
String hora_inicio = "14:20";
LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.parse(hora_inicio, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm"));
int hora = localTime.get(ChronoField.CLOCK_HOUR_OF_DAY);
int minutos = localTime.get(ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_HOUR);
```

Você pode utilizar esse código para subtrair:

```
// Java 8: java.time.LocalDateTime
LocalDateTime.now().minusHours(1)
```

Verifique também:

Apache DateUtils

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.7</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela sua resposta. Sou novo no java e em programação android studio, e não estou a entender uma coisa no código que enviou. Como é que consigo fazer a subtração de hora_inicio e hora_fim, convertendo cada uma em horas e minutos?      o código `LocalDateTime.now().minusHours(1)` subtrai a hora da String colocada a cima com a hora atual?