# Converter data de um formato para outro

Tags: java, android, data, simpledateformat

Estou fazendo um aplicativo para Android que utiliza a API da Apoid da Nasa.

Para isso, o usuário digita uma data, e ao clicar no botão, uma foto da galáxia referente à data digitada aparece. Estava tudo dando certo, até que resolvi formatar a data com o `SimpleDateFormat`. Para isso, o usuário digitaria a data no padrão brasileiro (`dd-MM-yyyy`) e converteria para o padrão ISO 8601 (`yyyy-MM-dd`). Mas toda vez que eu digito a data, seja em qualquer um dos formatos, o aplicativo simplesmente fecha. É bem provável que eu tenha errado algo no `SimpleDateFormat`. Segue o código a seguir:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String queryString = sdf.format(edit1.getText().toString());
```

Gostaria de saber pelo código feito a data digitada pelo usuário está sendo convertida e sendo guardada como `String` na variável `queryString`. E se há algo de errado, qual seria o erro.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O erro é que o método [`format`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DateFormat#format(java.util.Date)) recebe um [`Date`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date), mas você está passando uma `String`.

E na verdade a conversão não deve ser feita desta forma. Se você tem uma `String` em um formato e quer converter para outro formato, primeiro deve converter esta `String` para um `Date`, e depois converta este `Date` para o outro formato:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatoOrigem = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
Date data = formatoOrigem.parse("10-03-2020"); // string com a data no formato dia-mês-ano

SimpleDateFormat formatoDestino = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String formatoAnoMesDia = formatoDestino.format(data);
```

---

Apenas para deixar um pouco mais claro, conforme eu já disse [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/364683/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/368075/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/367704/112052), **datas não têm formato**.

Uma data é apenas um conceito, uma ideia: ela representa um ponto específico no calendário.

A data de "1 de janeiro de 1970", por exemplo, representa isso: o ponto específico do calendário que corresponde ao dia 1 do mês de janeiro do ano de 1970. Para expressar essa ideia em forma de texto, eu posso escrevê-la de diferentes formas:

- 01/01/1970 (um formato bem comum em muitos países, incluindo o Brasil)
- 1/1/1970 (formato americano, invertendo o dia e mês)
- 1970-01-01 (o formato [ISO 8601](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/LocalDate))
- Primeiro de Janeiro de 1970 (em bom português)
- January 1st, 1970 (em inglês)
- 1970年1月1日 (em japonês)
- e muitos outros...

Repare que cada um dos formatos acima é diferente, mas **todos representam a mesma data** (os mesmos valores numéricos do dia, mês e ano).

Dito isso, uma string como "10/03/2020" não é uma data. É apenas um texto que representa a data em um formato específico, mas não é a data em si. Em Java, textos são representados por uma `String` e datas podem ser representadas por um `Date`.

Quando você quer transformar uma `String` em um `Date`, está fazendo um *parsing*. Quando quer transformar um `Date` em uma `String`, está fazendo uma formatação. Por isso o método `parse` recebe uma `String` e retorna um `Date`, e `format` faz o contrário. E por isso que a conversão de uma `String` em um formato para outra `String` em outro formato deve ser feita em 2 passos.

---

Outra alternativa é usar a [API `java.time`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177129/112052) ([aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/190262/112052) tem instruções para usá-la no Android).

A ideia é similar, primeiro precisamos transformar a `String` em uma data (no caso, em um [`LocalDate`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/LocalDate), que é uma classe que representa uma data contendo apenas dia, mês e ano), e depois transformamos a data em outra `String`, no formato desejado:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

...

DateTimeFormatter formatoOrigem = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-uuuu");
LocalDate data = LocalDate.parse("10-03-2020", formatoOrigem);

String formatoAnoMesDia = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE.format(data);
// no caso do formato yyyy-MM-dd, toString() também funciona
// String formatoAnoMesDia = data.toString();
// ou ainda DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd") - mas eu prefiro usar o que já existe pronto na API
System.out.println(formatoAnoMesDia);
```